# I use ajax to send data but cannot receive data back from php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This function will get the value from the input and sent data with ajax to another php file. But I cannot get the result back from php file when I echo and store in ajax success function result.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.edit-button').click(function(){
        let clickpostid = $(this).prev().val();
        console.log(clickpostid);// I can see the input value
        $.ajax({
            url: "post/edit.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: { clickpostid },
            success: function(result){
                alert(result);
                //When I alert the result is blank not null or undefied.
            }
        })
    });
})
    

</script>
```

Below code will be in another file such as edit.php.

```
<?php 
include('../db.php');
if(isset($POST_['clickpostid'])){
      $id = $POST_['clickpostid'];
      echo $id;
   
}

?>
```

Comment: You should use `$_POST` instead of `$POST_`

Comment: Thank you. I didn't see. You live saver.

Comment: The data that you are sending is just a value rather than a name/value pair - perhaps more like `data: { 'clickpostid':clickpostid }`?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius — Err. No. Shorthand property definitions are very well supported: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#property_definitions

Comment: @quentin - thank you for the correction. Personally I find that a little confuzzling but will try to remember that!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your **edit.php** should be this:
You should use `$_POST` instead of `$POST_`

```
<?php 
include('../db.php');
if(isset($_POST['clickpostid'])){
      $id = $_POST['clickpostid'];
      echo $id;
   
}

?>
```

Comment: That makes it a TYPO. We just make a comment for a typo,which you did, and then delete the question. Typos are almost never any use to others which of course is the prime function of SO. **Not my DV**

Answer (score -2):

Please try this:

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.edit-button').click(function(){
        let clickpostid = $(this).prev().val();
        console.log(clickpostid);// I can see the input value
        $.ajax({
            url : "post/edit.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: { clickpostid: clickpostid },
            success : function (result) {
               alert(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

php:

```
<?php 
include('../db.php');
if(isset($_POST['clickpostid'])){
      $id = $_POST['clickpostid'];
      echo $id;
   
}

?>
```

Comment: That makes it a TYPO. We just make a comment for a typo and then delete the question. Typos are almost never any use to others which of course is the prime function of SO. **Not my DV**

Comment: Try what? This reads more like a game of spot-the-difference than an answer.

Comment: My Answar was not correct ??

Comment: @DelowarHossen — You have already got two comments explaining different things about this answer that make it a bad answer.